# filter acf relationship field

Tags: php, relationship, advanced-custom-fields, custom-fields

I'm trying to filter ACF relationship field.

```
function my_relationship_query( $args, $post, $field, $post_id ) {
    global $post;
    $try = get_field('manga_title', $post_id);
    $args['meta_query'] = array(array(
        'key' => 'manga_title',
        'value' => $try,
        'compare' => '=',));
    // return
    return $args;
}
    add_filter('acf/fields/relationship/query/name=chapterslist', 'my_relationship_query', 10, 3);
```

this is my code, i have a post object field in the post type that I'm working in, and I want to make its ID the value for filter. can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?